# Qt MetaObject inheritance checking from separate dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, shared-libraries

I'm creating a set of Qt plugins with common base types.  The app loads a plugin and categorizes the class it provides based on which base type it is a child of.

The base types are included in a static library, the derived types are built into a plugin including the static library, and the app also links against the static library.

Simplified, this looks like:

#### Static Library (common)

```cpp
class Base1 : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
};
// Qt moc code generation:
//    const QMetaObject Base1::staticMetaObject = {&QObject::staticMetaObject, /*etc*/};

class BasePlugin {
    public:
        virtual QObject* getObject()=0;
};
```

#### Shared Library (plugin)

```cpp
class Derived1 : public Base1 {
    Q_OBJECT
};
// Qt moc code generation:
//     const QMetaObject Derived1::staticMetaObject = {&Base1::staticMetaObject, /*etc*/};

class Derived1Plugin: public QObject, public BasePlugin {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        QObject* getObject() { return new Derived1; }
};
```

#### Application

```cpp
// setup plugin loader, load plugin
QObject* pluginObj = plugin.instance();

qDebug() << qobject_cast<Base1*>(pluginObj);    // Displays 0x0
qDebug()
      << pluginObj->metaObject()->superClass()  // Displays two different 
      << &Base1::staticMetaObject;              // pointer addresses
```

After some digging, essentially what is happening is that the metaobject for `Base1` is a static data member of `Base1`, and is getting initialized twice: once in the shared library and once in the application.  The metaobject `Derived1::staticMetaObject` was initialized in the plugin, and points to the `Base1::staticMetaObject` initialized in the plugin, and the name `Base1::staticMetaObject` in the app points to the metaobject initialized in the app.  This is true for both MSVC and GCC.  Thus, Qt decides that the derived class from the plugin is incompatible with the base class from the app.

My questions are:

- How are static members included in multiple executables initialized?
- Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting to do?
- How can I get my app to recognize that `Derived1` inherits `Base1`?

Comment: The [meta-object documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html) claims that `qobject_cast` should work across dynamic library boundaries, but I am running into the same problem as you.

Answer (score 0):

I got a slightly more complex approach to work by using the [Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtplugin.html#Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE) and [Q_INTERFACES](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_INTERFACES) macros.

The documentation on [Extending Qt Applications](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#the-low-level-api-extending-qt-applications) explains the use of these macros, but not all of the plugin machinery is necessary for the dynamic cast to work.

```
class BaseInterface
{
public:
  virtual ~BaseInterface() {}
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE( BaseInterface, "org.example.BaseInterface" )

class Base1 : public QObject, public BaseInterface
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_INTERFACES( BaseInterface )
public:
   virtual void foo() override {}
};
```

You should now be able to cast using `qobject_cast< BaseInterface* >(pluginObj)`.

Theoretically you could also define `Base1` itself as the interface, and add `Q_INTERFACES( Base1 )` to the declaration of `Derived1`, but I ran into [QTBUG-59460](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59460) when attempting to do this, plus it means every class inheriting `Base1` must remember to add that macro.